# Exchange hosting - looking for reliable alternative to BPOS

Tags: exchange-2010, bpos

Migrating from GoogleApps I'm very dissapointed from BPOS so far.
I'm sure there are reliable alternatives that offer Exchange 2010 hosting providers.
Would love to get first hand expirience.

Thanks,
Berry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably aware of this, but Microsoft doesn't currently offer Exchange 2010 hosting. [Office 365](http://office365.microsoft.com/en-US/online-services.aspx) will be their new hosted solution which will include Exchange 2010.

As far as other alternatives, [Rackspace offers exchange hosting](http://www.rackspace.com/apps/email_hosting/exchange_hosting/), but I couldn't seem to find which version they offer.

As far as first hand experience, currently we are using an in-house Exchange 2010 server, but plan to transition to Office 365 once its available.

Answer (score 1):

We just migrated to Office 365 off of on-premise Exchange.  We are a global company, but not very large, so providing quick email access to dozens of sites around the world was difficult on our own.

With Office 365 we let Microsoft worry about how to make email fast for all our distributed users.  It's nice not to have to solve that problem anymore, and so far Office 365 has been a good experience.  I'd recommend trying Office 365, so long as you understand that it has MOST of the functionality of BPOS, but not ALL of the functionality.

Also, Office 365 allows us to remotely wipe iPads and iPhones that are connected to Office 365 Exchange.  That was a big deal, since everyone wants to use an iPad and iPhone at work, but no one considers the security risks until a device is lost or stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Berry, how about managed hosting.   Install and configure exchange how you want it and or leverage the providers administration expertise and 24x7 availability commitments in their contract to offer you the service commitments and guarantee.

Comment: Not sure I got that you mean managed windows server while I'm maintaining the exchange server?

Comment: actually both, a lot of the hosting companies out there will manage specific items or an entire bench of administration including hardware, software, operating system, database, exchange, etc..

As mentioned, Rackspace does offer this, in addition Microsoft will have it available as well.  Logicworks is another you may want to look into.